# Fastest way to insert in-memory JSON data into Postgres, other than json_populate_record

Tags: json, postgresql, optimization, sql-insert

We ingest a lot of data, and one of the most time-consuming tasks is inserting data that NodeJS has in JSON format into the database.

Currently we're running a query like this, with the giant JSON array as a parameter:

```
INSERT INTO "newDataTable"  
SELECT batch.*  
FROM json_populate_recordset(null:: "newDataTable", ?) AS batch
```

This works, and is reasonably fast, but I wanted to know if anyone is aware of an even faster method of getting JSON data that is already in memory inserted into Postgres.

Comment: Have you tried using an ORM like sequelize? it works like a charm with Postgres. Instead of using direct queries, you manage your models with JSON and the ORM handles the queries. Also, you don't use JSON directly in the database, so it is faster.

Comment: If your data is from files, maybe you can directly ingest it from postgres without passing by a server. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/